# Response.cookies.add seems to not add cookie

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5

So I have an authentication method
which looks like the following

```
 public ActionResult SignIn( SignInModel model, string returnUrl )
        {
            if ( ModelState.IsValid )
            {
                var user = accountService.Authenticate(model.UserName, model.Password);
                if ( user != null)
                {
                    var cookie = ApplicationHelpers.SetupFormsAuthTicket( user, model.RememberMe );

                    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

                    if ( Url.IsLocalUrl( returnUrl ) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith( "/" )
                        && !returnUrl.StartsWith( "//" ) && !returnUrl.StartsWith( "/\\" ) )
                    {
                        return Redirect( returnUrl );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Redirect("/" );
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError( "", "The user name or password provided is incorrect." );
                }
            }
            return View( model );
        }
```

It gets hit as expected.

when the user has successfully authenticated it redirects to another url and the Globab.asax (Application_Postauthenticaterequest) gets hit.
my problem is that

```
 HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[ FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName ];
```

is always null.

I'm creating the cookie in the following 2 methods

```
public static HttpCookie SetupFormsAuthTicket( OutsourcingPrincipal user, bool isPersistent = false )
        {
            string encTicket = SetupFormsCookie( user, isPersistent );
            return new HttpCookie( FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket );
        }

        private static string SetupFormsCookie(  OutsourcingPrincipal user, bool isPersistent )
        {
            var serializeModel = new OutSourcingPrincipalSerializeModel();   
            serializeModel.FirstName = user.FirstName;
            serializeModel.LastName = user.LastName;
            serializeModel.Username = user.Username;
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string userData = serializer.Serialize( serializeModel );

            var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket( 1,
                                                    user.Username,
                                                    DateTime.Now,
                                                    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
                                                    isPersistent,
                                                    userData );
            var encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt( ticket );
            return encTicket;
        }
```

Can you spot what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: please add expiry of cookie as well. authCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);

Comment: expiry did not alleviate my problem - Request.Cookies[ FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName ]; is still null

Comment: Turns out my cookie is too large

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static int TicketVersion { get { return 4; } }

    public static FormsAuthenticationTicket Ticket
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                FormsIdentity _formsIdentity = (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
                if (TicketVersion != _formsIdentity.Ticket.Version)
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/SignOut.aspx");
                }
                return _formsIdentity.Ticket;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    public static string UserData
    {
        get
        {
            if (Ticket.IsNotNull())
            {
                return Ticket.UserData;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }

        }
    }
 public static void AddCookies()
 {

 FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(TicketVersion,
                                                                            name,
                                                                            DateTime.Now,
                                                                            DateTime.Now.AddDays(10),
                                                                            true,
                                                                            _userData);

        string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
        HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
        authCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
 }
```

Comment: please also direct SO that how his code is wrong. It would be easy to understand him

Comment: Sorry, this did not alleviate my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can get your data only after decrypting the cookies as shown below.

```
 public static User GetUserInformation()
    {

        HttpCookie authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

        // Decrypts the FormsAuthenticationTicket that is held in the cookie's .Value property.
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(authTicket.UserData);
        return obj;

    }
```

You will get FormsAuthenticationTicket information at "authTicket" and then after deserailizeing it you will get your data.